# Difficulty with an accumulator in a nested for loop

Tags: c++, matching, accumulator

I'm pretty new at C++, and I have to write code for a matching game, and I'm having trouble with the function that detects matches. 
    Below is a simpler, watered down version of the game I made to try to debug the match function. 
    Basically I have a bunch of numbers stored in a 2D array, and I need to cycle through the grid to see if there are any matches (3 of the same character in a row, vertically or horizontally, constitutes a match). The user gets one point for every match. 
    Every time there's a match, I need to accumulate a variable that stores the user's score. I think the code is pretty intuitive, the loops and if statements are checking the second and third elements after the ith element, and if they are all the same, a match has been detected.

The problem I'm having is that points are not being added to the count variable when they should. The "things" array is meant to emulate the game board, and I've designed it so it has at least one match, which my if statements don't seem to be detecting. How do I fix it so "count" will store points?

I've never posted anything on here before, so I'm sorry for the slightly screwy formatting, but here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int things[3][3] = {{3, 3, 3}, {2, 8, 4}, {3, 7, 2}};
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
      if (things[i] == things[i+1])
        count++;
      if (things[i] == things[i+2])
        count++;
      if (things[i] == things[i+3])
        count++;
      else
      {
        if (things[j] == things[j+1])
          count++;
        if (things[j] == things[j+2])
          count++;
        if (things[j] == things[j+3])
          count++;
       }
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valid indexes into your `things[3][3]` array are 0 through 2. You allow `i` and `j` to run as high as 3, and further access indexes as high as `i+3` and `j+3` - way out of bounds.

Comment: `things[i] == things[i+1]` compares pointers to the first element of `i`th and `i+1`th row, not values in those rows. The pointers are of course never equal; none of your conditions can ever be true.

Comment: Igor's points are both accurate. Additionally, your if statements for i+1, i+2, and i+3 are always run, but your else is chained to i+3. That means the only time the j checks are made is when i+3 is false. I would also address that for a 2-dimensional array, you'd usually index twice, e.g. things[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

> 3 of the same character in a row, vertically or horizontally, constitutes a match

Too code this correctly You need to first have the correct algorithm.

So this is how I would write it in pseudo code:

```
For every row:
     - For first n-2 columns in this row
         - if current match result and next 2 match results are the same : increment counter

For every column:
     - For first n-2 rows in this column
         - if current match result and next 2 match results are the same : increment counter
```